# Is it safe to pass a shared pointer using std::ref?

Tags: c++

I need to pass the shared pointer containing context object to callback function without moving ownership as all context objects are stored inside `unordered_map`.

I use `std::ref` to pass the shared pointer into call back function from parent function.

main -> get shared pointer from map -> parent function (accept shared ptr) -> callback function

```
void HTTPTransport::handleMessage(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket, std::shared_ptr<Connection> context,
                                  const std::variant<int, std::string> &message) {
                                      
    auto ctx = context->get();
    
    // Do Stuff
    
}

void HTTPTransport::handle(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket, std::shared_ptr<Connection> context) {
    ws->onMessage(std::bind(&HTTPTransport::handleMessage, this, std::ref(socket), std::ref(context), _1));
}
```

Is it safe to use `std::ref` in this case?

I remember reading somewhere that references to shared pointers should be avoided because of memory leaks.

There is one thing I forget to mention. The pointer may well as be empty at the time I pass because sometimes the connection get deleted from map when disconnect callback get called....

Comment: `without moving ownership` if the callback really does not have ownership, then why don’t you just pass the raw pointer to the object managed by the `shared_ptr` using `get()`.

Comment: I get the impression that it'd be better with `unique_ptr`s in the `unordered_map`

Comment: @TedLyngmo What about multi threads?

Comment: @jeffbRTC What do you mean? How are you protecting the objects from simultaneous access by multiple threads Today? Are you using the `atomic` support functions? It doesn't look like you're using the new `std::atomic(std::shared_ptr)` anyway. Are you using `mutex`es? If so, you can use `mutex`es for protecting access to the object through a `unique_ptr` too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Wording confused me.  There were this answer in which said I should use unique_ptr for single consumer while shared for multiple consumers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo And, I will have to use Mutex. It's lined up ...

Comment: Ok, if you use a `mutex` and the `unordered_map` is the sole owner of the resource, a `unique_ptr` seems like the best choice. Btw, do they even have to be `unique_ptr`s? Can't you store the `Connection` objects in the map directly or is there some polymorphism involved? Perhaps `std::optional<Connection>` if they are optional.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I thought I was using smart pointers because I want the objects to live longer, maybe I'm wrong, also I looked at some proxy implementations and they don't seem to use the dedicated Connection object at all (which is somewhat magical to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in your implementation it is not safe. In this code:

```
void HTTPTransport::handle(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket, std::shared_ptr<Connection> context) {
    ws->onMessage(std::bind(&HTTPTransport::handleMessage, this, std::ref(socket), std::ref(context), _1));
}
```

`context` is a local variable so storing a reference to it will have undefined behaviour when that reference is used. As your callback takes the `context` by value and `handle` takes it by value too you are already copying the `shared_ptr` twice anyway so there is probably little benefit storing by reference. Changing both methods to use references will mean the `shared_ptr` is only copied once (or if you keep using `std::ref` not at all) when calling `std::bind`:

```
void HTTPTransport::handleMessage(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket, const std::shared_ptr<Connection>& context,
                                  const std::variant<int, std::string> &message) {
    auto ctx = context->get();

    // Do Stuff
}

void HTTPTransport::handle(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket, const std::shared_ptr<Connection>& context) {
    ws->onMessage(std::bind(&HTTPTransport::handleMessage, this, socket, context, _1));
}
```

It doesn't sound like you are actually getting much benefit from using `shared_ptr` if you always only have a single owner of the pointer (the unordered_map). You might be better off having `std::unique_ptr` in your map then passing references between your methods:

```
void HTTPTransport::handleMessage(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket, Connection& context,
                                  const std::variant<int, std::string> &message) {              
    auto ctx = context.get();
    
    // Do Stuff
}

void HTTPTransport::handle(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket, Connection& context) {
    ws->onMessage(std::bind(&HTTPTransport::handleMessage, this, socket, std::ref(context), _1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this....One thing I had forgotten to mention. The context object may well as be invalid by the time I pass to callback function. See edit on my original post..

Comment: In that case you definitely want to store by value not reference

Comment: Can you really pass the context without std::ref? 

I remember I couldn't pass things to callback without std::ref but that's was with Objects... 

I will try in couple min

Comment: if it is a non-copyable object you need `std::ref` otherwise you can pass by value and it will be copied

Comment: Aren't you creating multiple references using std:ref in your unique ptr case (The last code example)?

Comment: what do you mean by `creating multiple references`? you don't really create references, having one, two or many references to an object doesn't change that object in any way, those references might even be optimised away at runtime

Comment: I thought that std::ref create an another reference <--> Connection& Context reference

Comment: The other issue I am getting with your unique ptr answer is initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue. Basically, calling foo(connectionMap->second.get()); results this.  And, foo signature is foo(Connection& context);

Comment: `std::ref` does create a "reference" (actually it's usually implemented as a pointer) but that shouldn't cause any harm? Try ` foo(*connectionMap->second.get());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229682/discussion-between-jeffbrtc-and-alan-birtles).

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Binding a reference to a local object (the shared pointer in this case) into a function object works if the lifetime of the referred object exceeds the lifetime of the callback funtion. Relying on such assumption is less safe in the sense that if the assumption is made by mistake, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

In many cases where calls to the callback are asynchronous, such assumption cannot be made.